# Android SQLiteDatabase.execSQL: Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I was a bit surprised when reading the doc for the [SQLiteDatabase.execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29). It says that *"Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported."*

I would not be surprised when reading it earlier, but my application used the command like:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE =
    "create table "
    + TABLENAME + "("
    + COLUMN_ID     + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + COLUMN_CODE   + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_NAME   + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_STOCK  + " integer,"
    + COLUMN_PRICE  + " real,"
    + COLUMN_LISTPRICE + " real"
    + ");"
    + "create index "
    + TABLENAME + "_idx on " + TABLENAME
    + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + ", "
          + COLUMN_STOCK + ", "
          + COLUMN_PRICE
    + ");";

...
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

I did not observe any error or exception (or I did not noticed). Does it mean that the index in my statement was not created? Or is the doc wrong?

Comment: For readability I would split the strings up and use transactions to prevent the performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks RvdK. I have already done it also because I want to drop and recreate index sometimes. However, the doc says it is not supported at all. That is the question. ;) Anyway, how a transaction can improve that?

Comment: If they doc says so, I tend to believe it ^^ (why it is, I don't know). If you do multiple execSQL simultaneously it will be faster if you start with beginTransaction, 2x execSQL, and then endTransaction. First check if needed ;)

Answer (score -2):

Check your concatination between Strings and make sure you leave a space between string variable. eg "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME "( "+ COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER" + COLUMN_NAME +" TEXT )"

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. In my opinion, it is completely unrelated to the question.